# Export ABS (Absolute database) to MySQL on MAC OSX

Tags: database, macos, delphi, migration

I have an password protected Delphi's ABS (Absolute database) database that I need to export to MySQL.

I do have the password but I can not find any software that would run on MAC OS X to do that.

I tried emulating ABS DBManager (Windows software) on MAC, but it didn't really work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I just said: it does not work on Mac.

Comment: You don't make yourself understood! Do you mean ABS DBManager doesn't run at all under some virtualization solution on MAC OS or it does indeed but without any capability to do MySQL export?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A direction to explore:

[Absolute Database](http://componentace.com/absolute_database_requirements.htm) also target Delphi XE2 as of version 6.20.

In theory, MacOS DBManager binary may be obtained through crossplatform compilation provided the availability of source code (there are some license granting that privilege).

Answer (score 1):

Run the AbsDB Manager on a Windows machine, export the data, move it to OSX and import to MySql there.

Comment: I do not have an access to Windows machine.

Comment: Without access to an executable that can read your DB, you are out of luck.

Comment: You can use VMWare or similar to run virtual machine if you can't accesss Windows machine.

Comment: When I saw "I tried emulating AbsDB Manager (Windows software) on MAC, but it didn't really work." I assumed he had already tried virtualization.

Comment: I agree with KevinDTimm, the answer is logical and correct and the downvote unmotivated (+1)

Answer (score 0):

You can ask for support from the vendor. Just my 5 cents.

Comment: The database is too big (900 MB >) for that.

Comment: I did not day to attach the database to a forum/mail/etc. I've said to ask the vendor about this. They can give you an advice.

Comment: @Guy: You can also ask the entity who handed the file to you to provide an appropriate version of it.