# Software to export Abs (Absolute database) to MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, delphi

Can anyone suggest any software to export Abs (Absolute database) to MySQL? I have already tried: http://www.componentace.com/bde_replacement_database_delphi_absolute_database.htm; which returns corrupted data ( [trying to decode data (exporting Abs to MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440064/trying-to-decode-data-exporting-abs-to-mysql) ) and ABC Amber Absolute Converter 1.03 which was unable to handle data (900 MB). Can anyone suggest alternatives? The database contains only one table (entries) and has one column in it WIDEMEMO. I am trying to export data to MySQL as stated above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [export ABS (Absolute database) to MySQL on MAC OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429548/export-abs-absolute-database-to-mysql-on-mac-osx)

Comment: Did you come up with a solution to it? PLease share.

Comment: @menjaraz, This was two years ago, I honestly don't remember. I remember this involved using SQLite. Probably I found a way to get data from Absolute database to SQLite and then to MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about writing your own?  If you've got one table with just one column, *this isn't a big programming project*.

Just open the table, loop through the records, writing them to temporary intermediate file. Then write another program to read them in to MySQL.

But, I agree with Radu: if you're in good standing with the Absolute people, they should be able to help you.  Maybe they, like me, can't figure why you just wouldn't write a quick and dirty program to do this.

Sorry if I've overlooked something that makes my suggestion unreasonable.

Answer (score -1):

As I've answered in your other question, have you tried to contact the vendor(Absolute database producer) and ask some advice from it?

Comment: Yes, I did. Two letters, no response.

Comment: and you have a fully commercial product? if you have a license I don't believe they will refuse to make support on a product sell by them. they must have a license agreement. and your client/company must have it also.  also I don't understand the -1 for your question. the person who made it should also post a comment/message to justify it.

Comment: also +1 because I don't see why this questions was marked with -1. In this way it remains 0, and if it still remain 0, then it can prove everybody that is a 'weak' question.

Comment: I provided a downvote on this answer because it should be removed and the content posted as a comment on the question.